# How do i change genymotion installation location?

Tags: software-installation, genymotion

I recently installed genymotion from my desktop so the genymotion installation binaries were created on my desktop using albert the installation path showed

`/home/alexander/Desktop/genymotion/genymotion`

However now i released the desktop is not my location since i like my desktop clean  so i have moved the related files to

`/home/alexander/.gen/genymotion`

How do i change the apps installation path to

`/home/alexander/.gen/genymotion/genymotion`

so that am able to search my app on apps

Using ubuntu 18.04

Comment: running the installation script `genymotion-***.sh` fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

Running the installation script with `./genymotion-***.sh` fixed the issue.